# Chrome userscript, which modifies tab key, stopped working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, userscripts

I have a simple chrome userscript which modifies the tab key for a particular webpage.
This worked fine until chrome v27 came. This is the code:

script.js:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Name
// @namespace      http://www.someNameSpace.com/
// @description    Description
// @include        http://weburl1.com/*
// @include        http://weburl2.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

function key_event(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 9){    //get tab pressed 
         /* do something here */
    }
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", key_event, true);
```

manifest.json:

```
{
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames" : true,
      "exclude_globs": [  ],
      "include_globs": [ "http://weburl1.com/*", "http://weburl2.com/*" ],
      "js": [ "script.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
   } ],
   "converted_from_user_script": true,
   "description": "Description",
   "key": "kVJUyHgHhlZtX2koEeV1ZF7yYHXfLyCyprC+I18+QzI=",
   "name": "Name",
   "version": "1.01"
}
```

Edit:
i turns out that the script is still running but only on initally loaded frames. So i added

"all_frames" : true,

to the manifest which did not work.

Is there anything i can do about it?
Thanks for your help

Comment: does it call the event listener or not at all?

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: No i didnt't tried it yet, but i tested the page in chrome debugger and found out that the script still works on the initially loaded frame but not on the subsequent ones.

Comment: hmm..seems also you have include globs, were you testing the extension on http://weburl1.com/*", "http://weburl2.com/ ?

Comment: Yes i tested it on the urls. There is a frameset which loads page1.htm. On page1.htm is a link which loads page2.htm. The script works only on page1.htm not on page2.htm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Chrome version 27.0.1453.110 the script is working again.
See also https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=242890

Answer (score 0):

Content scripts are not in the same context as that current page. 
You should inject the event handler  via another  tag

```
var actualCode = 'function key_event() {'
               + '    if(event.keyCode == 9){'
               +     'alert('tab');
               + '}';

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = actualCode;
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```